# Parallel.ForEach does not start all threads even though the ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads show 32754

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have a disconnect, perhaps mental, about available threads and Parallel.ForEach. The programs has a variable amount of work items to process. For this example 12. Just before calling the Parallel.ForEach I check the number of available threads, 32754 threads it tells me. Yet, when I call the Parallel.ForEach it only starts a random number of the threads, then as threads finish up it finishes with the task items until all are done.

So if the ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads tells me I have 32,744 why does it not start all of the works items? There is obviously, well it seems like there is, an adequate number of threads.

[Edit] After looking around some more I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621976/parallel-foreach-not-spawning-all-the-threads) and the answer which is good referenced [this](https://colinmackay.scot/2011/02/08/parallelisation-in-net-40-part-1-looping/) post. So I need to state that I have a 6-core, 12-thread i7 processor and at the time of executing the Parallel.ForEach my utilization is about 30%. So I think there is plenty of CPU left to launch all 12 work items.

TIA,
Doug

Comment: The duplicate that you linked to appears to answer your question. If you think that it doesn't please edit your question and make the distinction very clear.

Comment: Do keep in mind that each thread that is created uses approximately 1MB of RAM for its stack. So for 32,744  threads that's 32GB of RAM just to start those threads up. That's a lot of processing. It's much fast to limit the number of threads and to partition the `Parallel.ForEach` amongst a small set of threads.

Comment: I suggest that you try calling the `Parallel.ForEach` with the overload that accepts a `ParallelOptions` parameter, and specify a large value for the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) property. Also before calling `Parallel.ForEach` ensure that the `ThreadPool` has plenty of threads available by calling `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 10)`. Does any of these solve the problem you observe?

Comment: @Enigmativity, that makes some sense as I have 32GB of RAM. But the number of available threads is reported by the OS. I agree with you, you cannot will nilly create hundreds of threads. Bit in my case the maximum that would/could be created is 32. And with a relatively low CPU utilization number, it appears that there are cycles that could be used.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thanks! I was not looking setting the minimum value, only looking at the available threads and assuming the ThreadPool would do something intelligent. I will try your two suggestions and report back.